# How to make a bootable windows 7 USB (UEFI)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, usb, iso-image

I have been banging my head against the wall for weeks with this problem.

**The Problem:** I have ubuntu installed on my laptop and I want to dual boot with windows.

**Background**:

I'm trying to install 64 bit windows.

I have tried tools such as winusb, and the newer fork of it, these did not work.

Using rufus or a similar tool, I was able to make a usb that would boot but only in MBR / legacy boot mode. I need to boot in UEFI mode.

for rufus I followed the instructions found here:

http://www.techfleece.com/2015/07/08/how-to-create-a-bootable-windows-usb-drive-using-rufus/

Afterwards, I followed the instructions found here:

https://onetransistor.blogspot.cz/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html

This was the closest I have gotten, I was able to boot from the USB in UEFI mode, but it gives me an error:

```
Windows failed to start...

Status 0xc0000225
```

I have tried using different USB sticks, and even different windows iso's. No success.

Any suggestions?

All the iso's I have been using have been windows 7 iso's, am I better off using a windows 8 or 10 iso? I would really prefer not to.

Does anyone have experience making a bootable windows 7 usb? If so what method did you use? Any help much appreciated.

**Another note:**
The laptop came with windows pre-installed, I read on the ubuntu website that could be the problem. see the following link (toward the bottom of the page):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Does this mean it is not possible to dual boot with a laptop that came with windows pre-installed???

Comment: Edit your question and include the exact settings you use when with Rufus.  Are you attempting to install a 32-bit or 64-bit installation of Windows 7.  32-bit Windows 7 isn't compatible with UEFI.  Edit your question and include this vital information and I will reverse my vote.  Your question cannot be answered in it's current form.

Comment: Ok made the edits.

Comment: the procedure here https://onetransistor.blogspot.cz/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html is what got me a bootable drive (where I got the error) where as rufus didn't work at all

Answer (score -2):

It has to be FAT formatted (not NTFS, basically, usually FAT32).
Here's a good article about how to get the drive prepped, pretty easily:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/home_is_where_i_lay_my_head/2012/10/02/how-to-install-windows-7-or-8-from-usb-using-uefi/

After that, pay special attention to your BIOS settings.  For UEFI to work, you typically have to tweak a storage setting, and then reboot, as the UEFI values are assigned by the BIOS, dynamically.